# How to ban a country from assessing a Wordpress site without plugins

Tags: wordpress, geolocation

I currently need to ban a country from being able to gain access to our Wordpress website, but I do not want to use any plugins to achieve this task. Upon several unsuccessful Googling attempts I would like to know the best approach to complete this purely from code itself. Also if anyone attempts to go the website from the restricted country I would like to display a custom message. Also I want to add our internal static IP address to the list so that we can access the website without any issues.

Would appreciate if someone guides me through the right approach to achieve this.

Comment: If you do not want to use plugin then you will have to integrate some external service or ip-to-country database, which can derive the visitor's origin country based in his/her ip address. Search for the keyword "ip to country api".

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use plugins? Many good plugins are written for this purpose. Otherwise, it may be a bit too broad to answer on SO... but you can take a look at the source of [such a plugin](https://github.com/wp-plugins/iq-block-country) and do the same things yourself.

Comment: Because plugins would make the site more vulnerable and sometimes even slower, so I want to avoid the use of plugins to the maximum possible extent. Also with regards to the IP to country API, could you let me know how I could get it implemented; as in the overall steps? I had a look at one service called IPStack and they seem to be what you mentioned in terms of determining the country

Comment: There is a configuration and step process [here](https://www.ip2location.com/blockvisitorsbycountry.aspx)